# exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports

guys! For long time I can't fix the exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V

I've add all need jars into classpath:

- commons-beanutils-1.8.0
- commons-collections-2.1.1
- commons-digester-2.1.0
- commons-javaflow-20060411
- commons-logging-1.1.1
- itext - 2.1.5
- jasperreports - 5.1.0

I saw requirements for JasperReports [here](http://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/jasperreports-library-requirements), so I've all need libraries, but, anyway, I can't fix the bug

My code:

```
    class ForIReport {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

//        def conn = Sql.newInstance(
//                "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:1433;databaseName=twitter",
//                'sa',
//                'sunrise123',
//                'com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver')

//        Class.forName("com.microsoft.jdbc.SQLServerDriver").newInstance();
//        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:microsoft:sqlserver://localhost:1433", 'sa', 'sunrise123');

        def fileName = "C:/Users/avalev/Documents/iReport/First.jasper"

        def outFileName = "First.pdf"

        HashMap hm = new HashMap()

        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(fileName, hm, new JREmptyDataSource())


        JRExporter exporter = new JRPdfExporter()

        exporter.setParameter(
                JRExporterParameter.OUTPUT_FILE_NAME,
                outFileName);

        exporter.setParameter(JRExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, print)

        exporter.exportReport()

        println("Created file :" + outFileName)

    }

}
```

and description of exception

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (net.sf.jasperreports.extensions.ExtensionsEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.lowagie.text.pdf.PdfWriter.setRgbTransparencyBlending(Z)V
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReportToStream(JRPdfExporter.java:596)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.export.JRPdfExporter.exportReport(JRPdfExporter.java:419)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRExporter$exportReport.call(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCall(CallSiteArray.java:42)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:108)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.call(AbstractCallSite.java:112)
    at ForIReport.main(One.groovy:51)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I can create the instance of PdfWriter class (for check myself)

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please check your versions; `NoSuchMethodError` usually means that you have them out of sync (the JVM found the class, but the class looked different than expected).

Comment: @AndrewValevskiy You can always check the pom.xml of your *JR* library for getting all correct dependencies

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`jasperreports-5.1.0` needs `itext-2.1.7`.

You can see it in the [pom](http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/net/sf/jasperreports/jasperreports/5.1.0/jasperreports-5.1.0.pom) of the `jasperreports-5.1.0` project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7.js2</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

You need to upgrade the version of itext to version **2.1.7** minimum.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same `[runtime] error`.  What I realized was, I had the wrong jars for the "**batik**" library.  I got all version 1.7 jars from the `org.apache.xmlgraphics`.  I'm using jasper in this way:

```
 <dependency>
      <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
      <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
      <version>4.0.0</version>
   </dependency>
```

The batik, for example:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
      <artifactId>batik-anim</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Also, I made sure I only had one instance of iText in the pom:

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
   <artifactId>iText</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, when retrieving data from grid and writing to a PDF using

> flying-saucer-pdf

The isuue was **com.lowagie (itext)** and **org.xhtmlrenderer (flying-saucer-pdf)** versions incompatible,

use following,

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
        <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.xhtmlrenderer</groupId>
        <artifactId>flying-saucer-pdf</artifactId>
        <version>9.0.7</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have also came across same situation but finally succeeded to resolve it.

If you are using maven then add below dependency

`<dependency>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.lowagie.text</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>`

or download jar from below link and add to your buildpath

[com.lowagie.text_2.1.7](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.eclipse.birt.runtime.3_7_1/com.lowagie.text/2.1.7)

It will be of no use to add itext-2.1.7.jar , Also the latest version of that is itextpdf-5.5.9.jar

Answer (score 0):

If M. Abbas answer does not work then please use this dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
    <artifactId>itext</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

It works for me.